# What are the services that port 8140 puppet can offer ? Do we need to use SSH if using puppet?

Tags: security, networking, web-applications, port, puppet

I’ve come across a local server in my campus, all the opening ports and associative services  are ( After getting required permissions I did a full port scans ) `80 http` , `8080 tomcat` , `8009 ajp13` , `8140 puppet` . This server is managed remotely , things that are done remotely AFSIK are retrieving data , updating web applications.

The first question that came into my mind was how the server is accessed and managed remotely without any opening ports such as `telnet` or `SSH` ?

After reading few articles I got to know about port `*8140 puppet*` and its functionality , **to update and mange application remotely** especially when there are more than few servers with same applications.

But still what I don’t understand is how they retrieve data from server. Could it be through puppet ? Does puppet has another functionalities that I did not understand?

If the answer is **YES** , having `pupet` do we need `SSL` or `Telnet` which can put us in security troubles .

Answer (score 1):

> The first question that came into my mind was how the server is accessed and managed remotely without any opening ports such as telnet or SSH ?

It's hard to say, but perhaps it *isn't* remotely managed in the conventional sense.  It might be managed via Puppet, which would involve it periodically making requests to a remote server and updating itself based on the responses, but there still would need to be some way to get in for maintenance in the event that that breaks down.  For the machine in question, that might mean logging in to its physical console when needed.

On the other hand, it may be that some remote management is performed via a web-based management console.  The array of open ports could be consistent with that, but it seems doubtful, as I would expect such a service to be exposed only over HTTPS, and none of the open ports are among those conventionally associated with HTTPS services.

In any case, do note that *listening* on port 8140 doesn't speak to whether the machine is managed via a remote Puppet server.  Rather, it suggests that the machine may be a Puppet server itself.

> But still what I don’t understand is how they retrieve data from server. Could it be through puppet ?

Puppet clients retrieve data from Puppet servers in the usual network-service kind of way.  The standard server port for that is 8140.  The client connects to the server at that port, identifies itself and provides information about its current configuration, and receives a "catalog" describing how it should be configured.  The Puppet client then updates its machine as necessary to match the description in the catalog.

> Does puppet has another functionalities that I did not understand?

It's hard to judge what you do and do not understand about Puppet.  I'm inclined to guess that there's actually a lot that you don't understand about it, but I'm not sure that much of it has any bearing on the specific areas you're interested in.

> If the answer is YES , having `pupet` [sic] do we need `SSL` or `Telnet` which can put us in security troubles .

Puppet was designed from the beginning for security.  Puppet clients and servers identify themselves to each other via cryptographic certificates, and they employ cryptographically secure communication.  Use of Puppet does not introduce any need for insecure communication channels, as that would be judged by today's and historical standards.

Comment: Thnaks alot for explanation  , There is a `MySQL` database on the server could you  please tell me how data are retrieved from the server ? could it be through the same web application that we use on the server ? Is there any other possible way to get the data with above-mentioned protocols ? The server is on ethernet network so it's not connected to the internet so that might be the reason they don't bother using `HTTPS` for web-based management console.

Comment: @zolei, the standard mysql server port is not among those you say is open, so if the machine hosts a mysql server then either it is providing service on a port that is usually attributed to a different service, or (more likely) it is not accessible remotely.  The ports look like those of a JavaEE application server.  Most likely, mysql supports whatever applications are running on that application server.  Mysql could easily be open to them but closed to remote machines.  You cannot connect directly to the database if its service port is blocked from you.